# WEKA-generated models does not seem to predict class and distribution given the attribute index

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, decision-tree, prediction

### Overview

I am using the WEKA API 3.7.10 (developer version) to use my pre-made `.model` files.

I made 25 models: five outcome variables for five algorithms.

- [J48 decision tree](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html).
- Alternating decision tree
- Random forest
- LogitBoost
- Random subspace

I am having problems with J48, Random subspace and random forest.

### Necessary files

The following is the `ARFF` representation of my data after creation:

```
@relation WekaData

@attribute ageDiagNum numeric
@attribute raceGroup {Black,Other,Unknown,White}
@attribute stage3 {0,I,IIA,IIB,IIIA,IIIB,IIIC,IIINOS,IV,'UNK Stage'}
@attribute m3 {M0,M1,MX}
@attribute reasonNoCancerSurg {'Not performed, patient died prior to recommended surgery','Not recommended','Not recommended, contraindicated due to other conditions','Recommended but not performed, patient refused','Recommended but not performed, unknown reason','Recommended, unknown if performed','Surgery performed','Unknown; death certificate or autopsy only case'}
@attribute ext2 {00,05,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,50,60,70,80,85,99}
@attribute time2 {}
@attribute time4 {}
@attribute time6 {}
@attribute time8 {}
@attribute time10 {}

@data
65,White,IIA,MX,'Not recommended, contraindicated due to other conditions',14,?,?,?,?,?
```

I need to get the binary attributes `time2` to `time10` from their respective models.

---

Below are snippets of the code I use to get the predictions from *all* the model files:

```
private static Map<String, Object> predict(Instances instances,
        Classifier classifier, int attributeIndex) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    int instanceIndex = 0; // do not change, equal to row 1
    double[] percentage = { 0 };
    double outcomeValue = 0;
    AbstractOutput abstractOutput = null;

    if(classifier.getClass() == RandomForest.class || classifier.getClass() == RandomSubSpace.class) {
        // has problems predicting time2 to time10
        instances.setClassIndex(5); 
    } else {
        // works as intended in LogitBoost and ADTree
        instances.setClassIndex(attributeIndex);    
    }

    try {
        outcomeValue = classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));
        percentage = classifier.distributionForInstance(instances
                .instance(instanceIndex));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    map.put("Class", outcomeValue);

    if (percentage.length > 0) {
        double percentageRaw = 0;
        if (outcomeValue == new Double(1)) {
            percentageRaw = percentage[1];
        } else {
            percentageRaw = 1 - percentage[0];
        }
        map.put("Percentage", percentageRaw);
    } else {
        // because J48 returns an error if percentage[i] because it's empty
        map.put("Percentage", new Double(0));
    }

    return map;
}
```

---

Here are the models I use to predict outcome for `time2` hence we will use index 6:

```
instances.setClassIndex(5);
```

- [`ADTree` model for `time2` prediction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjdmfvqi3gnal6b/bosom.100k.2.adt.MODEL)
- [`J48` model for `time2` prediction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlk6enuo8xk0e34/bosom.100k.2.j48.MODEL)
- [`RandomForest` model for `time2` prediction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7enbiuvzi9y0wd7/bosom.100k.2.rf.MODEL)
- [`LogitBoost` model for `time2` prediction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k1l3b38k20e0cb/bosom.100k.2.lb.MODEL)
- [`RandomSubSpace` model for `time2` prediction](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8a0ferlorfpjznm/bosom.100k.2.rs.MODEL)

### Problems

- As I said before, `LogitBoost` and `ADTree` have no problem in this straightforward method compared to the other three, as I followed the ["*Use WEKA in your Java code*"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) tutorial.
- **[Solved]** Based from my tweakings, [`RandomForest`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) and [`RandomSubSpace`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/RandomSubSpace.html) returns an 
  `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if told to predict `time2` to `time10`.

  ```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
      at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.distributionForInstance(Bagging.java:586)
      at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest.distributionForInstance(RandomForest.java:602)
      at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:70)
  ```

  The stack trace points the root error to the line:

  ```
  outcomeValue = classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));
  ```

  > **Solution**: I had some copy-paste error during the `ARFF` file creation for the binary variables `time2` to `time10` regarding `FastVector<String>()`'s assignment of values to the `FastVector<Attribute>()` object. All ten of my `RandomForest` and `RandomSubSpace` models are working fine right now!
- **[Solved]** [`J48` decision tree](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html) has a new problem now. Instead of not providing any predictions, it now returns an error:

  ```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
      at weka.core.DenseInstance.value(DenseInstance.java:332)
      at weka.core.AbstractInstance.isMissing(AbstractInstance.java:315)
      at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45Split.whichSubset(C45Split.java:494)
      at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.getProbs(ClassifierTree.java:670)
      at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.classifyInstance(ClassifierTree.java:231)
      at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.classifyInstance(J48.java:266)
  ```

  and it traces to the line

  ```
  outcomeValue = classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));
  ```

  > **Solution**: actually I randomly ran the program with `J48` and it worked - giving the outcome variable and associated distributions.

---

I hope someone can help me sort out this issue. I really do not know what is wrong with this code as I have checked the Javadocs and examples online and the constant predictions are still persistent.

(I am currently checking the main program for the WEKA GUI but please help me out here :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only looked at the RandomForest problem for now. It is because the Bagging class
extracts the number of different classes from the data instance itself, and not from the model.
You say in your text that time2 to time10 are binary, but you just don't say it in your ARFF file,
and so the Bagging class has no clue about how many classes there are.

So you just have to specify in your ARFF file that time2 is binary, e.g.:
@attribute time2 {0,1}

and you won't get any Exception any more.

I've not looked at the J48 problem, because it may be the same issue with ARFF definition.

Test code:

```
  public static void main(String [] argv) {
      try {
        Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("bosom.100k.2.j48.MODEL");
        J48 c = (J48)cls;

        DataSource source = new DataSource("data.arff");
        Instances data = source.getDataSet();
        data.setClassIndex(6);        

        try {
            double outcomeValue = c.classifyInstance(data.instance(0));
            System.out.println("outcome "+outcomeValue);
            double[] p = c.distributionForInstance(data.instance(0));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it now, thank you for the response and I'll update you once I'm done.

Comment: Yay! I managed to solve the problem with `RandomSubSpace` and `RandomForest` - it was during the ARFF creation. Can you please look into `J48`? The problem is still the same. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Edit: the problem with my `J48` model is now behaving like the one experienced by `RandomForest` (I think) but it is the only one not working now :/

Comment: I just tried with your J48 model and I don't have any Exception: it returns 0 ?

Comment: You're correct, no Exceptions and 0 is returned but have you tried the `distributionsForInstances()`?

Comment: Yes it gives me [1.0;0.0] which is ok with its answer 0. Decision trees do not return probas, so it's OK to have such values. I'm not sure the problem comes from the J48 model, but I suspect it rather comes from the instances that you create when you're testing. Can you save your instances on disk for which it fails, and publish them ?

Comment: (1) Can you please share how you got [1.0;0.0]? (2) I just use arbitrary combinations of the attribute values and they all fail in `classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));`. I use one instance only.

Comment: Thank you, so J48 will only return 1.0 or 0.0 as the prediction distribution right?

Comment: Yes, because decision trees don't produce scoring; they just make a sequence of hard decisions so you cannot get real values as with the other classifiers. I don't know how to format my piece of code correctly in stackoverflow, anyway...

Comment: I always thought I could get something like "0.457 for outcome 1.0" from a J48 because I already tried it in the GUI version :(

Comment: Hello, IT IS WORKING NOW, THE J48! I randomly ran the program and I got a probability from the J48! (I ran it four times because I can't believe it wow). Anyway, thank you for all the help today! I wish you all the best ^_^

Comment: Well, even with hard decisions like with a decision tree, it's possible to output real numbers; Although I don't now all the details of J48 implementation in Weka, I know that the C4.5 algorithm, when run on a corpus, actually compute ratios of instances in the corpus; so I suspect the real numbers that you have seen with J48 actually correspond to such corpus ratio, which cannot really be thought of as probabilities. And I doubt decision-tree based algorithms can give reliable probability distributions from a single example. At least, I wouldn't interpret them as pdf :-)

Comment: Thank you again, I'm really into machine learning after I've learned what I can do with it and thank you the heads up on J48! I'll study WEKA's implementation then as you pointed out :D