# Weka- Array Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java, weka

I am fairly new to weka, but I had this working in java with the naive bayes- I have switched to wanting to use J48, and keep running into this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1236
```

It's on the line:

```
double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
```

I have tried printing (unlabeled.instance(i)); and it gives me the instance. Just whenever I try to use "classify instance" I get an error.

The training part of the program appears to work fine- I get a print out of how many it's correctly classified etc. I have tried copying some of the data from my test arff file over to the arff file to be classified, and that hasn't stopped the error, so I feel fairly sure my arff file to be classified is formatted okay.

I will post the rest of the code below- As I said it worked fine when I used naive bayes. Any clue as to why I'm having this issue?

```
ConverterUtils.DataSource source = new ConverterUtils.DataSource("training.arff");
Instances train = source.getDataSet();

train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

StringToWordVector stringToWord = new StringToWordVector();                        
stringToWord.setInputFormat(train);
Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(train, stringToWord);

J48 tree = new J48();
tree.buildClassifier(newData);

// evaluate classifier and print some statistics
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
train.setClass((newData.attribute("class")));
eval.evaluateModel(tree, newData);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
eval.crossValidateModel(tree, newData, 10, new Random(1));

Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.arff")));
unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);
Instances labeled = Filter.useFilter(unlabeled, stringToWord);

for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.size(); i++) {
    double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
    labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
}

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputgroup.arff"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is still sth. wrong with your arff file.

Have look at [WEKA-generated models does not seem to predict class and distribution given the attribute index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808033/weka-generated-models-does-not-seem-to-predict-class-and-distribution-given-the).

Comment: There was nothing wrong with my arff. I was applying the filter to labelled, and then trying to classify unlabelled. I should have used the filter on the unlabelled and then tried to classify it.